# How to check "" (blank character values) in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I can use the command like dataframe$column %in% "" to check blank character values in a vector, but this doesn't work for a dataframe alone. So, what command/function will be used to check these values in a dataframe.

Comment: You will need to iterate over each vector in a dataframe to do this.

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: If you want to return a data frame with the same dimensions as your original one with `TRUE` or `FALSE` values, you could just use `dataframe == ""` instead.

Comment: I was wrong, @nrennie has the best answer

Comment: You can also do slightly odd things like `dat[as.matrix(replace(dat, , unlist(dat) %in% c("","l")))] <- NA` to avoid looping, but it's pretty ugly.

Comment: Given you haven't stated what you are wanting to achieve there could be a number of responses to your question. In addition to the comment from @nrennie, I have assumed you wish to modify the blank values? Sample data: `df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,"",6,7), b = c(1,"",3,4,"",6,7))` and to modify the blanks use something like `df[,1:2][df[,1:2] == ""] <- NA`